# VB.net datagridview refuses to show rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable, row

I have a datagridview control on a form in a WinForms project that happily displays all the rows of the datatable that is assigned as its datasource - but only once.  This happens in the btnSettings.Click event handler (code below).  Any time I hit the button a second time (to refresh the table), the headers appear but no rows appear.  I am running VS2020 fully updated.  I have tried all sorts of things but to no avail.  The function GetSettings returns a datatable.  I have verified that it returns 11 columns and 40 rows every time.  Oddly, if I sort the table by clicking any of the column headers, the rows magically appear.
I'm happy to provide more info, or to be told I am doing something stupid.  Code essentially identical to this does not have this behavior in another project.

```
    Private Sub btnSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSettings.Click

        Dim t As DataTable

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        dgvSettings.Visible = False
        btnSettings.Enabled = False

        ' Get the settings and show them in the grid.
        dgvSettings.DataSource = Nothing
        t = GetSettings()
        dgvSettings.DataSource = t

        btnSettings.Enabled = True
        dgvSettings.Visible = True
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

    End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you get rid of all that code and just use `dgvSettings.DataSource = GetSettings()`?

Comment: Exactly the same thing.  The first time, the table populates and all rows are shown, but subsequent times only the column headers are shown.

Comment: I couldn't guess why it's not working as is but if where to use an actual bindingsource for your dgv then problem should solve itself

Comment: Nope - the whole bindingsource approach fails the same way.  I also tried using the legacy datagrid and I get the same behavior.